# Update with a select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'oldTable' with city inside who contain the fields id, city and postal_code.

This table is the one i actualy use for the user define his city but i wanna upgrade this table so i dowload a new table with all the city inside.

This new table 'newTable' contain the field id, old_id, city and postal_code.

What i want is to put in the field 'old_id' from 'newTable' the id who correspond to city of the 'oldTable' so i do this sql :

```
UPDATE newTable
SET old_id = oldTable.id
FROM oldTable
WHERE oldTable.city= newTable.city
AND oldTable.postal_code = newTable.postal_code
```

But i have this error :
You have an error in your sql syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM oldTable WHERE ...'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for an `update` with `join` in MySQL is:

```
UPDATE newTable JOIN
       oldTable
       ON oldTable.city = newTable.city AND
          oldTable.postal_code = newTable.postal_code
    SET newTable.old_id = oldTable.id;
```

Comment: Thank it's work i already try with an join but i don't put the SET at the good place.